# Keep loading.gif animated when manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page which has a function on document.ready which essentially does this:

- Shows Loading panel (with loading.gif)
- AJAX call to external server
- Creates HTML markup to add to the DOM
- Adds the markup to the page ( <- loading.gif stops animating)
- Hides loading panel

Works great. But the loading.gif stops as the page is updated. Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the markup generated huge?

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when the size of the markup being added is very large. The browser has to go through a lot of repaint and reflow cycles to accommodate this markup. And if there is javascript that acts on this huge markup added, that further slows down the process. Since there is a single UI thread that's painting the page (and animating your loading.gif) and executing the script, hence it momentarily stops the animating gif image.